# How to fix MOUSEMOTION and collidepoint unexpected results?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a little 2D game in order to learn python and pygame. I've made a menu on which there are 2 buttons (PLAY and QUIT). PLAY button start the game et QUIT button leave the game.

Now i want to display a red circle when the mouse pass on a button. I'm using MOUSEMOTION and collidepoint.

The code is working and a red circle is displayed when i pass the mouse on the buttons but when I put the mouse elsewhere on the window, the red circle still remains.

```py
def menu():

    global Font, Xplay, Xquit, Yplay, Yquit, X_rect_play, Y_rect_play, X_rect_quit, Y_rect_quit, done, QUIT1, pos_quit, BLACK, WHITE, RECT_QUIT, RECT_PLAY, pos_play
    pygame.font.init()

    circle_play = False
    circle_quit = False

    while not done:
        screen.fill(BLACK)      
        RECT_QUIT = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (X_rect_quit,Y_rect_quit,250,50))
        RECT_PLAY = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (X_rect_play, Y_rect_play,250,50))
        pos_play = (325,166)
        PLAY1 = Font.render("PLAY", True, BLACK)

        screen.blit(PLAY1,pos_play)
        screen.blit(QUIT1, pos_quit)

        if circle_play:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (310,174), 13)
        if circle_quit:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (310,274), 13)

        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                circle_play = RECT_PLAY.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                circle_quit = RECT_QUIT.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

I expect that the red circle is removed when I move the mouse.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the code that draws buttons inside the while loop, and make sure that you clear the screen every frame.

To fix circle automatically disappearing, you need to make a variable that tracks if circle is visible.

```
def menu():

    global Font, Xplay, Xquit, Yplay, Yquit, X_rect_play, Y_rect_play, X_rect_quit, Y_rect_quit, done, QUIT1, pos_quit
    circle_play = False  # will be true when circle on the play button will be visible
    circle_quit = False

    while not done:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        RECT_PLAY = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (X_rect_play, Y_rect_play,250,50))
        pos_play = (325,166)
        PLAY1 = Font.render("PLAY", True, BLACK)

        screen.blit(PLAY1,pos_play)
        screen.blit(QUIT1, pos_quit)

        if circle_play:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (310,174), 13)
        if circle_quit:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (310,274), 13)

        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                circle_play = RECT_PLAY.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                circle_quit = RECT_QUIT.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be the good method but the red circle only apppear for the time of the mouvement because of the update(). I need to move the mouse again to redisplay the circle. If I remove the display.update(), the menu does not appear automatically  and i need to collide the mouse with the buttons.

Comment: OK, I will fix it.

Comment: Ok, It's working now! I must be careful with the position of my code and loop. Thanks.